# Easy steps for adding the imported content on one single page for display

Tags: feeds

I have imported the data using the [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module from an Excel file.

But as I am new it has created multiple article nodes. I want all these articles to be shown under one article list page. Please explain step by step how can I move forward.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to do it. Follow these steps, to set a page listing all articles--

- Download views & keep it in **sites/all/modules** folder.
- Enable **`Views`** & **`Views UI`** from your module list.
- Under **Structure** click **View** & **Add a new View**.
- Select **Content** under show & **Article** of type.
- Give a name to it & check **Create a page**.
- Save & continue.
- Give a path to the created view page.
- Now you can access your path like `$basth_url/(your given path)`.

Thats it.

Comment: Thanx alot Rajeevk